# regex utilities in vscode api?

Tags: javascript, regex, vscode-extensions

Are there any set of language-specific utilities (in the vscode extension api) to help find expressions within a script?

Although I have a specific example below, the question above is more general, e.g. how are language parsers built? are they all *just a bunch of regular expressions*?

My specific example that motivated this question:

I want to find if there are any calls to a method called `.getInfo()` without any arguments provided, in a javascript document. For example:

```js
/*
Examples of getInfo with and without a callback function.
*/
// foo.getInfo method in a comment. 
foo.getInfo(callback);
foo.getInfo  ();
foo.getInfo
();

foo
.getInfo(
    // single comment
)

foo.getInfo     (
// Testing 
/* Multiline 
comment
*/
);


foo.getInfo(
    print
)

foo.getInfo 
//comment
();

foo.getInfo 
//comment
(
    //testing
);
```

In this script there are six `.getInfo()` calls without any arguments, and two calls with arguments (one with `callback`, and another one with `print`). I am only interested in finding the ones without arguments.

My naive attempt to solve this with a regex is getting ridiculous. I asked bard for help, but so far none of the solutions match all six cases.

For example, this solution only matches three cases:

```js
const regex = /\b\.getInfo\s*\((?:\s*(?:\/\/.*?|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))*\s*\)/g;
```

this other solution also matches three cases (but not the same three):

```js
const regex = /\b\.getInfo\s*(?:\/\/.*?|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/)*\s*\(?\s*\)/g;
```

Rather than trying different ridiculously long regular expressions, I wonder if there is a more general API for doing this within vscode api (or maybe a javascript library)? Also looking for other general suggestions for tackling these type of problems.

This is a small working version of `extension.ts`:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('test.parse', () => {
    const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    if (editor) {
        let document = editor.document;
        const documentUri = document.uri;
        if (documentUri.scheme==='file'){
            const regex = /\b\.getInfo\s*(?:\/\/.*?|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/)*\s*\(?\s*\)/g;
            const sourceCode = document.getText();
            const matches = sourceCode.match(regex);
            if (matches) {
              console.log(`Found ${matches.length} instances of .getInfo() called without arguments.`);
              console.log(matches);
            } else {
              console.log("No instances of .getInfo() called without arguments found.");
            }
        }
    }
    });
    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);

}
export function deactivate() {}
```